# Execute exe in a schedule from Azure Devops

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, scheduled-tasks, exe

Is there a way to execute an exe on a scheduled basis (once/twice every day of the week) in azure devops. Not able to find the right task to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to execute an exe on a scheduled basis (once/twice everyday of the week) in azure devops

The answer is yes.

We could add a [Command Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task in a build or release pipeline to run a program from the command prompt, specify the `.exe` of the console application from your repos location, for example: `"$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Tools\ConsoleApp.exe"`:

[image]

**Then**, we move to the **Trigger** tab, there is an option **Scheduled**, which we could set the scheduled basis:

[image]

If you want to schedule the task/build **twice** every day of the week, you could add one more schedule.

**Update:**

> How to add app configs specific to each envs here in this step? Any
>   idea?

You could achieve it by the release pipeline with multi-stage:

[Define your multi-stage continuous deployment (CD) pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops)

Each stage for each envs.

> Additionally this requires a build every time correct? Is there a way
>   to eliminate that?

Yes, this requires a build every time, otherwise, there will be no trigger to run the `.exe`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to add app configs specific to each envs here in this step? Any idea?

Comment: Additionally this requires a build every time correct? Is there a way to eliminate that?